# ANR Investigating with trace.txt

Tags: android-anr-dialog

First of all, Thank for visitor who take a look this question,
I faced heavy issue with ANR because trace.txt is not clearly, I cannot extract any information from that file. So I post the file in order to everyone help me:

```
    "main" tid=1 Native 
        "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
          | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7562bf90 self=0x7edfc9aa00
          | sysTid=24254 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7ee4547a98
          | state=S schedstat=( 6402587709 172480935 6997 ) utm=548 stm=91 core=4 HZ=100
          | stack=0x7febfad000-0x7febfaf000 stackSize=8MB
          | held mutexes=
          #00  pc 000000000001bdac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
          #01  pc 0000000000069fec  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+96)
          #02  pc 000000000003c1d8  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk (???)
          at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.nativeOnVSync (Native method)
          at org.chromium.ui.base.WindowAndroid.a (PG:142)
          at bQf.a (PG:16)
          at bPT.doFrame (PG:22)
          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:914)
          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:718)
          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:647)
          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:902)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:836)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
          at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:232)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6802)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
        "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" tid=2 Native 
        "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native (still starting up)
          | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x7ed820d000
          | sysTid=24259 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7edf2ff450
          | state=S schedstat=( 93518534 6800078 91 ) utm=7 stm=1 core=0 HZ=100
          | stack=0x7edf201000-0x7edf203000 stackSize=1021KB
          | held mutexes=
          #00  pc 000000000001bdac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
          #01  pc 00000000000e89cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+156)
          #02  pc 000000000046f4ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadPool7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+248)
          #03  pc 000000000046e994  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+124)
          #04  pc 000000000046e2b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
          #05  pc 000000000006a8bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
          #06  pc 000000000001dc28  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

Comment: did you ever find any information about what this is?  Looks like something in Chrome, and from my device stats, it's mostly LG devices running Android 7.x.

Comment: Do you have the MillennialMedia ad SDK in your app?  And if so, did you recently update it?

Comment: this is an issue already reported to google, but it looks like they doesnt treat this one seriously
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=857459